# how can I match a username with the key of a property in an object which is in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have an array in which objects are included. I want to get the username from client and check whether that username exists in keys of objects or not.
But I don't know how to match that username with the keys of objects!

Here is a simple form of my code :

```
var usersArray = [
    {
        name : "Simon",
        password : 123
    },
    {
        name :"David",
        password : 456
    }
];
```

Comment: You **do not** want to return credentials to the frontend ...

Comment: Why are you using an array at all? If you're using a db, just query the db with an appropriate call, if not: this is super absolutely not how you work with user credentials and you should find an established user management package instead of rolling your incredibly insecure own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if an array contains an item, you can use `Array.prototype.some`, `Array.prototype.every`, `Array.prototype.find`, or a `for` loop.

Here's all 4 ways:

```js
var usersArray = [
    {
        name : "Simon",
        password : 123
    },
    {
        name :"David",
        password : 456
    }
];

const userNameFromClient = 'David';

// use a `for of` loop (using a `while`, or a regular `for` loop would also work)

// A loop allows us to iterate through an entire collection.
// Once we find an item satisfying a condition, we can signal that.

// This is a good starting point that explicitly
// shows the mechanics of looping over a collection
// to find an item satisfying a condition
for (const user of usersArray) {
  if (user.name === userNameFromClient) {
    console.log(true);
  }
}

// Since this operation is quite frequent in programming,
// most languages give us tools and methods to achieve
// above in a more declarative fashion and with less code

// For your particular case, the most common approach
// would be to use the `some` method on the array.

// We want to return true if there exists at least one item
// in our array that satisfies our condition

// Code bellow will return true if one object in `usersArray`
// has a property `name` whose value is a string
// equal to the string contained in the
// `userNameFromClient` variable
console.log(
  usersArray.some(user => user.name === userNameFromClient)
)

// Another option is to use the find method.

// Since `find` will return the actual user object
// that satisfies a condition instead of a boolean `true` or `false`,
// we would have to convert the returned result
// into a Boolean ourselves
console.log(
  Boolean(usersArray.find(user => user.name === userNameFromClient))
)


// The `some` method also has a cousin called `every`
// which can be used in this situation but is a little
// bit messy because it requires multiple negations

// You can see what I mean if we explain the operation
// in plain English:

// If not every item in a given array does not satisfy a condition
// return true

// Above is just a convoluted way of saying if there exists
// at least one item satisfying a condition, return true

// Code bellow will return true if one object in `usersArray`
// has a property `name` whose value is a string
// equal to the string contained in the
// `userNameFromClient` variable
console.log(
  !usersArray.every(user => user.name !== userNameFromClient)
)
```

Comment: Which one is going to be the most "typical" way?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var usersArray = [{
  name: "Simon",
  password: 123
}, {
  name: "David",
  password: 456
}];

let name = "David";

let result = usersArray.some(x => x.name === name)
console.log(result)
```